# number of links in a webpage with webview

Tags: android, uiwebview, webview

I have defined some webview and I open some webpage on it

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://mypage.com/");
```

My question is how can I count the number of links in that webpage ?

my first idea was to parse the html code and to count the "href" string in that html, but this solution sound like a noob solution to me. Is there more intelligent way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the HTML I think you can do that with a simple javascript function that sends the count data back to Android. You can see an answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5264612/571353)

The function in Javascript to count links can be as simple as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function countLinks()
   {
      var all_a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      return all_a.length;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare a JavaScriptInterface in android code:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
   Context mContext;
   /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
   JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
       mContext = c;
   }
   /** Get number of links */
   public void getNumOfLinks(int numOfLinks) {
       // Use the count as you like
   }
}
```

Then add this interface to your webview, when you call it:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

Finally in the HTML code get the number of links from DOM and pass it to the java code via the interface:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Android.getNumOfLinks(document.getElementsByTagName("a").length)
</script>
```